# Improve speed of gradient descent

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to maximize a target function `f(x)` with function `scipy.optimize.minimum`. But it usually takes 4-5 hrs to run the code because the function `f(x)` involves a lot of computation of complex matrix. To improve its speed, I want to use gpu. And I've already tried `tensorflow` package. Since I use `numpy` to define `f(x)`, I have to convert it into tensorflow's format. However, it doesn't support the computation of complex matrix. What else package or means I can use? Any suggestions?

To specific my problem, I will show calculate scheme below:

1. Calculate the expectation [image]:

   -where `H=x*H_0`, `x` is the parameter
2. Let `\phi` go through the dynamics of Schrödinger equation [image]

   -Different `H` is correspond to a different `\phi_end`. Thus, parameter `x` determines the expectation
3. Change `x`, calculate the corresponding expectation
4. Find a specific `x` that minimize the expectation

Here is a simple example of part of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cmath
from scipy.linalg import expm
import scipy.optimize as opt

# create initial complex matrixes
N = 2 # Dimension of matrix
H = np.array([[1.0 + 1.0j] * N] * N) # a complex matrix with shape(N, N)
A = np.array([[0.0j] * N] * N)
A[0][0] = 1.0 + 1j

# calculate the expectation
def value(phi): 
    exp_H = expm(H) # put the matrix in the exp function
    new_phi = np.linalg.linalg.matmul(exp_H, phi)
    # calculate the expectation of the matrix
    x = np.linalg.linalg.matmul(H, new_phi)
    expectation = np.inner(np.conj(phi), x)
    return expectation

# Contants
tmax = 1
dt = 0.1
nstep = int(tmax/dt)
phi_init = [1.0 + 1.0j] * N


# 1st derivative of Schrödinger equation
def dXdt(t, phi, H): # 1st derivative of the function
    return -1j * np.linalg.linalg.matmul(H, phi)

def f(X):
    phi = [[0j] * N] * nstep # store every time's phi
    phi[0] = phi_init
    # phi go through the dynamics of Schrödinger equation
    for i in range(nstep - 1):
        phi[i + 1] =  phi[i] - dXdt(i * dt, X[i] * H, phi[i]) * dt
    # calculate the corresponding value    
    f_result = value(phi[-1])
    return f_result

# Initialize the parameter
X0 = np.array(np.ones(nstep))
results = opt.minimize(f, X0) # minimize the target function
opt_x = results.x
```

PS: 
Python Version: 3.7

Operation System: Win 10

Comment: Please provide the code, so we can give a proper answer. From experience, I can say that changing libraries usually comes with a major increase in complexity with such problems.
Potential next steps:
+ Optimize Function Computation (caching, approximation, etc..) \n
+ Parallelize

Comment: [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) would probably give a significant performance boost to the calculation but it is hard to gauge without a [mcve].